# Combing code with menu selection - python

Tags: python

I am working on combining a collection of scritps together with a menu selection that would allow me to select the corresponding script that is selected;

Ex -

```
# import libaries
import socket
import os
import threading
import struct

 # import other programs
import nc

from ctypes import *
from netaddr import IPNetwork, IPAdress

# ask for network infomration
host = raw_input("Enter Your Machine Ip: ")
subnet = raw_input("Enter Subnet of Network: ")

# what would you like run
menu = {}
menu['1'] = "NC"
menu['2'] = "blah"
menu['3'] = "blah

while True:
    options = menu.keys()
    options.sort()
            for entry in options:
                    print entry, menu[entry]

    selection=raw_input("What would you like to do?")
    if selection == '1':
            print "Runing NC..."
            print "Please wait..."
            if __name__ == "__main__':
                    execut main:
```

as of now it is hitting an error at -> for entry in options:

Comment: This code does not run. It has syntax errors. E.g. `execut main:` is definitely not valid Python code. Please read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and modify your question accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

Python is sensitive to indents. The `for entry in options:` should be on the same level as the row above it.

If you use an IDE like Pycharm for example, it will help catch things like this for you while you're coding.

Answer (score 0):

The indentation is wrong. The `for entry in options` line shouldn't be indented:

```
   options = menu.keys()
   options.sort()
   for entry in options:
       print entry, menu[entry]
```

There's also a missing quote: `menu['3'] = "blah` should be `menu['3'] = "blah"`